# access id of a nested document in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to write a `put` method in express for a nested document in mongoose.

I cannot access the id for the nested document.

```
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b8d1ecbb745685c31ad8603"),  
    "name" : "abc",  
    "email" : "abc@gmail.com",  
    "projectDetails" : [   
        {  
            "technologies" : [   
                "abc",   
                "abc"  
            ],  
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8d1ecbb745685c31ad8604"),  
            "projectName" : "abc",  
            "projectDescription" : "abc",  
            "manager" : "abc",  
            "mentor" : "abc"  
        }  
    ],  
    "__v" : 0  
}
```

I am trying to access the id ("5b8d1ecbb745685c31ad8604") so that I can update the projectName.

I cannot think of how to write a put method for the same. Please help! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.findOne()` and then `save()` th update the document instead of `model.findOneAndUpdate()`.

```
var projectId = "5b8d1ecbb745685c31ad8604";
var newProjectName = "def"; 
model.findOne({'projectDetails._id': projectId}, (err, data) => {
    if (data) {
        data.projectDetails.forEach((project) => {
            if (project._id == projectId) {
                project.projectName = newProjectName;
            }
        });
        data.save();
    } else {
        // throw error message
    }
})
```

Comment: will this have method have to be used similarly if I want to update any other entity under projectDetails?

Comment: Yes, you can update any under projectDetails with this method.

Comment: I tried working it. Did not reflect in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.put('/api/project/:id',(request,response)=>{
const projectId = request.params.id;
const projectName = "test";
db.users.update({"projectDetails._id":projectId},{$set:{"projectDetails.$.projectName":projectName}},function(err,data){
    if(data){

    }else{

    }
})})
```

> Instead of forEach try above query

Comment: what would be the equivalent express query for the same?

Comment: It does not work. It does not even show an error nor does it reflect any change in the database.

Comment: Check properly you are using correct database name and projectId is not empty.Apply console on database name and check everything is fine or not because query is working fine it is properly tested.